# require_once not working in server

Tags: php

**Folder**

**fb/fb-include.php**

**index.php**

i was going to access my fb-include.php in my index.php and i have this line at my index page.

```
require_once('/fb/fb-include.php');
```

it work on my localhost wamp , but when i update to server , it wont work anymore.

i also try this

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

require_once('$root/fb/fb-include.php');
```

what i did wrong ? is there any way i get into that folder still using require_once or should i use include ?

Comment: `require_once('fb/fb-include.php');` try this

Comment: try require_once($root.'/fb/fb-include.php');

Comment: M A SIDDIQUI and Dr Manish Joshi thank for reply , i tried both , still no answer , it will only work if i change the require_once to include.

Comment: Only works if you change require_once to include? Nope. It just doesn't throw a fatal.

Answer (score 0):

update your code like this

```
require_once $root.'/fb/fb-include.php';
```

or

```
require_once($root.'/fb/fb-include.php');
```

and need to sure root give your rootpath

or you can use like this

```
require_once('fb/fb-include.php')
```